# Shoreline assesment via buffer

Tags: buffer, digital-shoreline-analysis-system, shoreline

I've been looking around but haven't found an answer to match.

I have a number of endpoint rates (EPR, I'm working on shorelines), and I want to know if it's possible to create a buffer based on the EPR numbers. So say a point has moved 2 meters, but another point has moved -0.5, is there a way to calculate a buffer based on each unique EPR number?
Hope it makes sense, and that I have clarified my question.

Edit (17.04.2019):
I'm using ArcMap, working with the DSAS software-extension. My plan is to try and create a disaster-assessment map, and I want to show how the shoreline could potentially move, based on past movement.
So I have a set of EPR numbers, representing whether the coast has eroded or accreted, and I want to, based on the EPR numbers, visualise where those points could be located within a number of years if that makes sense.

Comment: It would not be bad if you added the following information: what software do you use, and more details, for example, I need to build a dynamic linear buffer relative to measurement points or add a picture of what you would like to receive, and even better: I tried to build point buffer zones so and so, but they do not solve my problem ...

Comment: Thank you. I have tried to add more information in the original post now. I also, don't want to burden with a lot of unnecessary information, but your suggestions definitely make sense.